# Impossible to plot a currency value into a plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a dataframe with a numerical column in euro (ex: 7 000 €) that I want to show on a map with the tool `.plot`.

```
df
        item price
    1   A   7 000 €
    2   B   10 880 €
    3   C   10 990 €

maps = df.plot()
maps

    ValueError: could not convert string to float: '7 000 €'
```

I get an error message because it considers the column as an object and not a float.

```
df.dtypes
    item object
    price object   
    dtype: object
```

I first deleted the `' €'` characters with `rstrip`.

```
df['price'] = df['price'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip(' €'))
df
        item price
    1   A   7 000
    2   B   10 880
    3   C   10 990
```

Then I tried to convert the column to float, but impossible because there is a separator (space) of thousands (ex: 7 000).

```
df.price = pd.to_numeric(df.price, errors='ignore')
maps = df.plot()
maps

    ValueError: could not convert string to float: '7 000'
```

When I replace the `' '` to `''`, I get no error message, however when I show the dataframe, I always have the separator, and the column is always considered an object (no possibility to plot it)

```
df['price'].replace(' ','', inplace=True)
df
        item price
    1   A   7 000
    2   B   10 880
    3   C   10 990
```

I can't get out of this. Can you help me please ? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use  [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) to ensure the plot function considers it a number.

```
df['price'] = df['price'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '').replace('$', ''))
df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'])
```

Comment: Thank you @Roelant but it doesn't work. My dataframe still contains ` ` and `€`. 
Then, error message of `df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'])` is `ValueError: Unable to parse string "7 000 €" at position 0`

Comment: Thank you Roelant ! I have checked the code and know it works. Also, I have made another mistake by merging 2 dataframes on the wrong order (merge(B,A) instead of merge(A,B)). This prevented to show the plot.

Comment: Perfect. Happy to hear! If my answer helped you to solve it, please accept it as the solution :)